# How to kill python script with bash script

Tags: python, linux, bash, raspberry-pi3

I run a bash script with which start a python script to run in background

```
#!/bin/bash

python test.py &
```

So how i can i kill the script with bash script also?

I used the following command to kill but output `no process found`

```
killall $(ps aux | grep test.py | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $1 }')
```

I try to check the running processes by `ps aux | less` and found that the running script having command of `python test.py`

Please assist, thank you!

Comment: did you find the keyword "test.py" in process info by `ps` ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use `pkill` command as

```
pkill -f test.py
```

(or) a more fool-proof way using `pgrep` to search for the actual process-id

```
kill $(pgrep -f 'python test.py')
```

Or if more than one instance of the running program is identified and all of them needs to be killed, use [killall(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/killall) on Linux and BSD

```
killall test.py
```

Comment: This is not working if you run more than one instance of the same script.

Comment: Great! Nice solution to kill all instances of a script

Comment: works like a champ for multiple python processes in the background in linux. I've never used pkill but it's certainly easier than kill or killall. nice

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `!` to get the PID of the last command.

I would suggest something similar to the following, that also check if the process you want to run is already running:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -e /tmp/test.py.pid ]]; then   # Check if the file already exists
    python test.py &                   #+and if so do not run another process.
    echo $! > /tmp/test.py.pid
else
    echo -n "ERROR: The process is already running with pid "
    cat /tmp/test.py.pid
    echo
fi
```

Then, when you want to kill it:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -e /tmp/test.py.pid ]]; then   # If the file do not exists, then the
    kill `cat /tmp/test.py.pid`      #+the process is not running. Useless
    rm /tmp/test.py.pid              #+trying to kill it.
else
    echo "test.py is not running"
fi
```

Of course if the killing must take place some time after the command has been launched, you can put everything in the same script:

```
#!/bin/bash

python test.py &                    # This does not check if the command
echo $! > /tmp/test.py.pid          #+has already been executed. But,
                                    #+would have problems if more than 1
sleep(<number_of_seconds_to_wait>)  #+have been started since the pid file would.
                                    #+be overwritten.
if [[ -e /tmp/test.py.pid ]]; then
    kill `cat /tmp/test.py.pid`
else
    echo "test.py is not running"
fi
```

If you want to be able to run more command with the same name simultaneously and be able to kill them selectively, a small edit of the script is needed. Tell me, I will try to help you!

With something like this you are sure you are killing what you want to kill. Commands like `pkill` or grepping the `ps aux` can be risky.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -ef | grep python
```

it will return the "pid" then kill the process by

```
sudo kill -9 pid
```

eg output of ps command: 
user    13035  4729  0 13:44 pts/10   00:00:00 python (here 13035 is pid)

Comment: The `kill -9` command has a different behaviour from `kill`. Pay attention when using the `-9` option.

Answer (score 0):

With the use of bashisms.

```
#!/bin/bash

python test.py &
kill $!
```

`$!` is the PID of the last process started in background. You can also save it in another variable if you start multiple scripts in the background.

Answer (score 0):

```
killall python3
```

will interrupt ***any and all*** python3 scripts running.